# Clearing the event does not stop other threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am working on a scraper that rotates the ips, i have created a small mvp in a notebook that works as expected:

```
import logging
import time
import random
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
)

class Controller(object):

    def __init__(self, event):
        self.start_time = datetime.now()
        self.event = event

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            if self.event.is_set():
                rand_sleep_time = random.randint(1, 10) / 5
                logging.debug("Sleeping for %.2f secs" % rand_sleep_time)
                time.sleep(rand_sleep_time)
                logging.debug("Werking")
            else:
                time.sleep(1)

    def blocker(self):
        while True:
            rand_sleep_time = random.randint(3, 6)
            logging.debug("Sleeping for %.2f secs" % rand_sleep_time)
            time.sleep(rand_sleep_time)
            if datetime.now() > self.start_time + timedelta(seconds=10):
                self.event.clear()  # only stop the execution for when the ip is updated
                logging.debug("ALL THREADS SLEEP NOW!")
                time.sleep(10)
                self.event.set()  # you can now proceed with the computations
                self.start_time = datetime.now()

start_time = datetime.now()
e = threading.Event()
e.set()
c = Controller(e)

for thread in range(NUM_THREADS):
    t = threading.Thread(target=c.worker, name='Thread-Worker-{}'.format(thread+1))
    t.start()

threading.Thread(target=c.blocker, name='Thread-Blocker-1').start()
```

So the workers above do some work, then the blocker halts all of them for a brief moment of time, while it updates the "ip", and then the workers start the work again. Taking this logic and implementing it into production, this fails (because I assume the workers do not stop). Unfortunately, I cannot include all of the code, but here is the main part. Hopefully, this is enough, as other parts are not related to the fact that the Ip-Updater does not stop other threads. The only difference in this implementation is that I have used classes, perhaps that should be changed (because the methods have `self` arg and I'm chaning it. But if the Ip-Updater were to successfully stop the other threads, then there should be no problem, no?):

```
class ThreadedNewsParser(object):
    """
    This little guy parses the news with multiple threads and dynamically changes the ip of the sessions
    """

    def __init__(self, update_ip_in, num_threads, date_start, date_end):
        assert isinstance(num_threads, int)
        assert num_threads > 0
        assert any(isinstance(date_start, type_) for type_ in [datetime, date])
        assert any(isinstance(date_end, type_) for type_ in [datetime, date])

        self.start_time = datetime.now()
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.event.set()
        self.update_ip_in = update_ip_in

        self.check_ip_url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'
        autolog("STARTING WORK ON IP: {}".format(session.get(self.check_ip_url).text), logging.debug)

        self.num_threads = num_threads
        self.date_start = date_start
        self.date_end = date_end

        self.dates = [date for date in date_range(date_start, date_end)]
        self.p = DailyCompanyNewsParser(2008, 1, 1)  # the date here does not matter

    def worker(self):
        while len(self.dates) > 0:
            if self.event.is_set():
                print("THREAD WERKING!")
                pause = random.randint(1, 5) / 5
                autolog('THREAD SLEEPING %.2f' % pause, logging.debug)
                time.sleep(pause)
                if len(self.dates) > 0:
                    date = self.dates.pop(0)
                    self.p.get_news_for_all_stocks(verbose=True, date_=date)
            else:
                print("THREAD SLEEPING")
                time.sleep(10)  # so that the threads do not check if the event is set instantaneously

    def ip_updater(self):  # this is the blocker
        while len(self.dates) > 0:
            autolog("IP_UPDATER SLEEPING FOR: {}".format(self.update_ip_in / 4), logging.debug)
            time.sleep(self.update_ip_in / 4)  # do not check the condition every instance

            if datetime.now() > self.start_time + timedelta(seconds=self.update_ip_in):
                print("ALL THREADS SLEEP NOW!")
                autolog("ALL THREADS SLEEP NOW!", logging.info)
                self.event.clear()  # Make all other threads sleep so that we can update the IP
                time.sleep(10)
                get_new_ip()
                self.start_time = datetime().now()
                # autolog("Obtained new IP address: {}".format(session.get(self.check_ip_url).text), logging.debug)
                autolog("ALL THREADS WAKE UP NOW!", logging.info)
                print("ALL THREADS WAKE UP NOW!")
                self.event.set()

    def run(self):
        for thread in range(self.num_threads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker, name='Thread-Worker-{}'.format(thread+1))
            t.start()

        threading.Thread(target=self.ip_updater, name='Thread-IPUpdater-1').start()
```

Rewriting everything so that `event` and `start_time` are global variables does not solve the issue.. For example:

```
class ThreadedNewsParser(object):
    """
    This little guy parses the news with multiple threads and dynamically changes the ip of the sessions
    """

    def __init__(self, update_ip_in, num_threads, date_start, date_end):
        assert isinstance(num_threads, int)
        assert num_threads > 0
        assert any(isinstance(date_start, type_) for type_ in [datetime, date])
        assert any(isinstance(date_end, type_) for type_ in [datetime, date])

        self.update_ip_in = update_ip_in

        self.check_ip_url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'
        autolog("STARTING WORK ON IP: {}".format(session.get(self.check_ip_url).text), logging.debug)

        self.num_threads = num_threads
        self.date_start = date_start
        self.date_end = date_end

        self.dates = [date for date in date_range(date_start, date_end)]
        self.p = DailyCompanyNewsParser(2008, 1, 1)  # the date here does not matter

    def worker(self):
        global event
        while len(self.dates) > 0:
            if event.is_set():
                print("THREAD WERKING!")
                pause = random.randint(1, 5) / 5
                autolog('THREAD SLEEPING %.2f' % pause, logging.debug)
                time.sleep(pause)
                if len(self.dates) > 0:
                    date = self.dates.pop(0)
                    self.p.get_news_for_all_stocks(verbose=True, date_=date)
            else:
                print("THREAD SLEEPING")
                time.sleep(10)  # so that the threads do not check if the event is set instantaneously

    def ip_updater(self):  # this is the blocker
        global start_time
        global event
        while len(self.dates) > 0:
            autolog("IP_UPDATER SLEEPING FOR: {}".format(self.update_ip_in / 4), logging.debug)
            time.sleep(self.update_ip_in / 4)  # do not check the condition every instance

            if datetime.now() > start_time + timedelta(seconds=self.update_ip_in):
                print("ALL THREADS SLEEP NOW!")
                autolog("ALL THREADS SLEEP NOW!", logging.info)
                event.clear()  # Make all other threads sleep so that we can update the IP
                time.sleep(10)
                get_new_ip()
                start_time = datetime().now()
                # autolog("Obtained new IP address: {}".format(session.get(self.check_ip_url).text), logging.debug)
                autolog("ALL THREADS WAKE UP NOW!", logging.info)
                print("ALL THREADS WAKE UP NOW!")
                event.set()

    def run(self):
        for thread in range(self.num_threads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker, name='Thread-Worker-{}'.format(thread+1))
            t.start()

        threading.Thread(target=self.ip_updater, name='Thread-IPUpdater-1').start()
```

Comment: Tested your first version (without `global`) after stripping down the code (`autolog`? `DailyCompanyNewsParser`? `get_new_ip`?). Except for `ip_updater` raising a TypeError on `start_time = datetime().now()`, sending your workers into an infinite sleep cycle, it looks to be doing what you want. The dependencies seem a bit suboptimal though. If your `ip_updater` raises an exception it either never pauses your threads or does so indefinitely as in your code above. If all of your workers raise an exception/die prematurely, `ip_updater` runs indefinitely as len(self.dates) never reaches 0.

Comment: `autolog` is just a logger, `DailyCompanyNews` deals with parsing the urls, `get_new_ip` generates a new ip to scrape with. The idea of the `ip_updater` is to put every single thread into a sleep mode, update the ip, and then continue. But what I have is precisely what you got, it gives me the `TypeError`...

Comment: My point was that no one looking into your issue knows what these do, therefore your examples don't qualify as MCVE. We have to modify the code you presented here in order to run it. Since your example works after said removal of the references to these objects (and the correction of the datetime.now() call), chances are that your issue is caused by what you decided not to share with us.

Comment: The TypeError comes from the mentioned line `start_time = datetime().now()` in `ip_updater`. It must be `start_time = datetime.now()`. If this _really_ is your issue, including the exception and the traceback in your question would have probably yielded an answer within minutes of publishing the question ...

Comment: It is my issue. I do not understand what causes it. The very first code snippet does not produce it. The second and third do.

Comment: Because in the fist code snippet you did `datetime.now()`, which is correct, in the second and third you do `datetime().now()`, which is incorrect. **Parenthesis after `datetime` and before `.now()`. Remove them!**

Comment: Embarrassing. Thank you very much.